# Wordpress gallery displays all the images attached to a post/page

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

Wordpress galleries have a strange way to work, in my opinion. I explain:

- Wordpress gallery shows in the post ONLY the images that have been
  uploaded in the current post. If you add in the gallery an image that
  already was in Media library, it will not be showed!
- After having create a gallery, if I remove an image from the gallery
  it will be showed anyway
- The gallery displays all the images attached to the post (also
  featured thumbnail and embedded images) although these images were
  not included in the gallery

I'd call all of this a bug.

The question: **Is it possible to show in the post ONLY the images (both the uploaded ones and the ones that already was in Media libray) that are included in the gallery?**

**Notice**: without using the shortcode `[gallery exclude="..."]` and without uploading the images directly from Media library?

P.S. To display the gallery in the post I'm using this script:

```
<ul>
<?php $images = get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $post->ID . '&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC');
foreach( $images as $img_id => $img_r ) :
     $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'thumb', true );
     $full = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'full', true ); ?>
     <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $full[0] ?>">
             <img src="<?php echo $thumb[0] ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title( $img_id ) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title( $img_id ) ?>">
        </a>
     </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a bug, that's just how the gallery works. It will only display images attached to a post, if you want to add an already-uploaded image to the gallery then you'll need to attach the image to the post from the Media menu.

You can use gallery shortcode to display the images or alternatively you can use the codes on http://www.wpcodesnipps.com/display-images-attached-post/ to display the images.